# Is there a way to transfer items between characters?

Tags: mir4

Is there a way to transfer items **directly** from one character to another within the same account?

I'm thinking of creating a new a character in my account but I want to give it some starter items if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's no option to transfer items to another character even if it's the same account. There's a private warehouse a character can use but it's not shared between characters (I tried it and it doesn't work)

Right now what people do to sell items via the gold marketplace at a low price and buy it via the other character. This is however risky and may get you banned as it's what's called a ghost trade.